# What is the thing called in GNOME 3 that appears when you press the super key?

Tags: gnome-shell, terminology

When using Ubuntu 16.04 with the GNOME desktop and pressing the <kbd>super</kbd> key it causes an overlay to appear that displays Workspaces, overview of Applications, Application Launcher on the left, and search at the top.

I'm wondering what this feature is called?

Comment: See also [terminology \- What are the elements of the GNOME Desktop? \- Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1126811/what-are-the-elements-of-the-gnome-desktop/1261669#1261669)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's generally called the ["(Activities) Overview"](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/Design#Activities_Overview):

> #### Activities Overview
>
> This is a separate view designed to enable users to get an overview of
> their current activities and to enable effective focus switching (in
> this regard, the overview is a facilitator and a mediator, not a
> destination). The top bar continues to be displayed in the overview in
> order to provide a familiar landmark and visual anchor.

It's composed of:

- the dash,
- the window picker,

  [image]
- the application picker,

  [image]
- the search,
- the workspace switcher, etc.

We also have a tag for it: [activities-overview](/questions/tagged/activities-overview)

Comment: What is [the name](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1126811/what-are-the-elements-of-the-gnome-desktop) of [the Search field and the ensuing window](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-desktop/uploads/93d8b4f6472e4eda714d592aba49c7a7/image.png)? Unity calls that the "Dash". Is there a "HUD"?